# Insert into table while selecting a field as identity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL question.

I am writing something similar to this SQL statement.

```
if object_id('G2Records') is not null
drop table g2records

WITH G2Records AS
 (
SELECT *
FROM table_A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B ON A.id = B.table_A_Id
 )
SELECT identity(1,1) AS id, *
INTO table_c
FROM G2Records
```

SQL gives error on the identity.

Basically, is there a way to insert an identity field into a table that I will be dropping every time I run this SP?? And obviously the table_c.id will reset back, which is okay.

But the reason why I would really want something like this is because table_a specially gets fields added often, so I don't want to write a CREATE script for table_c with exact fields that are from table_a and some of _b because than every time someone adds fields to table_a or _b, I would need to come back to this SP and modify. And it's not like the other departments tell me when they add new fields.

The identity field is just for some new development we are working on and it's needed.

The SQL does not have to be like what I have, just long as will accomplish what I am asking :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the table you are selecting into have this column as an identity? If it does, just insert the other fields and it will handle the identity. If this is just an integer field, look into the ROW_Number() function to get a unique row id.

Comment: @liebs SELECT INTO creates a new table, so "the table you are selecting into" doesn't even exist yet.

Comment: @liebs - what Aaron said :) yeah the table does not exist at that point.

Comment: I see that now, looks like he beat me to the answer below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to the `IDENTITY()` function is a data type, and it must be specified. This is clearly outlined in [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx), which should usually be your first resource when you encounter errors and/or have guessed at syntax and it doesn't work. When posting a question here, please don't say `SQL gives errors` but rather post the actual error message. e.g.:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near '1'.

That doesn't seem like it would be very helpful, but it is much better to be specific than vague.

Try:

```
;WITH G2Records AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM dbo.table_A AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.table_B AS b
  ON A.id = B.table_A_Id
)
SELECT IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS id, *
----------------^^^ salient part right here
  INTO dbo.table_c
  FROM G2Records;
```